# Detect cluster outliers

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, outliers

I have a dataset where every data sample consists of 10-20 2D coordinates points. The data is mostly clean but occasionally there are falsely annotated points. For illustration the cleany annotated data would look like these:

[image]
[image]

either clustered in a small area or spread across a larger area. The outliers I'm trying to filter out look like this:

[image]

the outlier is away from the "correct" cluster.

I tried z-score filtering but this approach falsely marked many annotations as outliers

```py
std_score = np.abs((points - points.mean(axis=0)) / (np.std(points, axis=0) + 0.01))
validity = np.all(std_score <= np.quantile(std_score, 0.95, axis=0), axis=1)
```

Is there a method designed to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a typical clustering problem, and if the data looks as you suggested the KMeans from scikit-learn should do the trick. Lets look how we can do this.

First I am generating a data sample, which might look somewhat like your data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

np.random.seed(1) # For reproducibility

cluster_1 = np.random.normal(loc = [1,1], scale = [0.2,0.2], size = (20,2))
cluster_2 = np.random.normal(loc = [2,1], scale = [0.4,0.4], size = (5,2))

plt.scatter(cluster_1[:,0], cluster_1[:,1])
plt.scatter(cluster_2[:,0], cluster_2[:,1])
plt.show()

points = np.vstack([cluster_1, cluster_2])
```

This is how the data will look like.

[image: Points dataset, with 2 clusters]

Further we will be doing KMeans clustering.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 2).fit(points)
```

We are choosing n_clusters as 2 believing that there are 2 clusters in the dataset. And after finding these clusters lets look at them.

```
plt.scatter(points[kmeans.labels_==0][:,0], points[kmeans.labels_==0][:,1], label='cluster_1')
plt.scatter(points[kmeans.labels_==1][:,0], points[kmeans.labels_==1][:,1], label ='cluster_2')
plt.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:,1], label = 'cluster_center')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This will look like as the image shown below.

[image: Custered points]

This should solve your problem. But there ares some things which should be kept in mind.

- It will not be perfect all the times.
- Might be a problem if you don't have any outliers. Can be solved through silhouette scores.
- Difficult to know which cluster to discard (Can be done through locating the center of the clusters (green colored points) or can also be done by finding the cluster with lesser number of points.

Endnote: You might loose some points but would automate the entire process. Depends upon how much you want to trade off in terms of data saved versus manual time saved.

Comment: k-means sound not that suitable to me, mostly for cases when the points are spread out all over the plane and most of the data is clean. Also, I don't think I can afford to calculate iterative algorithm as k-means for every data sample I have as I have hundreds of thousands of samples.

Comment: @DominikFicek Is your dataset just consisting of 25 points each. Secondly I don't think it is so expensive computationally. And the runtime for this is fast. Can you just plot how extreme one of the dataset is? The examples that you show, KMeans should work for that.

Comment: My dataset has many samples, each consisting of 10-20 points. What I want to achieve is to remove outliers from every sample so I would have to calculate k-means for every sample. Even then I'm not really convinced k-means is the way here, I would imagine there is a statistical test or something similar that achieves this.